# HTML form set as POST but method GET performed

Tags: html, forms

On a webshop that I've build I'm having trouble with posting a HTML form. In almost every case (99,9%) this is working as expected, but in some specific cases it goes wrong. And I really have no clue. So that's why I'm posting my question here.

My HTML form looks like:

```
<form id="gegevens" class="form-horizontal margin-bot-15" method="post" action="<?=HOST?>/winkelmand/gegevens-controleren/" role="form" autocomplete="off">
  // Some input forms and a lot of HTML
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-shopping-cart" value="order">
</form>
```

Now the page `/winkelmand/gegevens-controleren/` should be accessed with a `POST`, not a `GET`. In 99,9% of the cases this is also a `POST` as expected. But in the other cases, it's a `GET` and no data is posted to this page.

I can see this in the access logs because the URL `/winkelmand/gegevens-controleren/` is accessed via `GET`. I've had this issue twice at the same day (and 7 days before no issue). The ammount of orders places is high enough to say that a real small amount of orders go wrong. The only thing I've noticed from the accesslog is that both orders are placed from a Mac with Safari and that they are redirected from another website to this site.

User agent: `"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10) AppleWebKit/600.1.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/600.1.25"`.

On my own Mac with Safari and OSX 10.10 I did the same as one of the customers, same redirect same steps but everything goes like expected on my Mac.

Does anyone have any clue what might cause this or what I can check?

**UPDATE:**
The suggestion of that they enter the URL manually is very very unlikely but might be possible.

I'm using jQuery validation to validate the form. Below this javascipt.

```
 $("#gegevens").validate({

    focusInvalid: false,
    rules: {
      email: {
        required: true,
        emailFull: true
      }              
    },
    messages:{
      email: {
        required: "Er is geen e-mailadres ingevuld.",
        emailFull: "Vul een geldig e-mailadres in."
      }
    },
    errorClass: 'has-error',
    validClass: 'has-success',
    ignore: "",
    errorElement: "div",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {

      if(element[0].name == "betaalmethode"){
        // Bij element betaalmethode melding tonen na de lijst
        $("ul.list-betaalmethode").after(error);
      }else if(element[0].name == "voorwaarden"){
        // Bij voorwaarden melding tonen na het element
        element.parent().after(error);
      }
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).nextAll('.glyphicon').removeClass('hidden glyphicon-ok has-succes').addClass('glyphicon-exclamation-sign has-error');
      $(element).addClass("input-error");
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).nextAll('.glyphicon').removeClass('hidden glyphicon-exclamation-sign has-error').addClass('glyphicon-ok has-success');
      $(element).removeClass("input-error");
    },
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
      if (!validator.numberOfInvalids()) {
        return;
      }else {
        // De eerste melding plaatsen in de meldingBody
        // element ID plaatsen in data-focus van de OK button
        // Popup tonen
        $("#meldingBody").html(validator.errorList[0].message);
        $("#meldingOk").data("focus", validator.errorList[0].element.id);
        $("#melding").modal('toggle');

      }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
      if ($(form).valid()) {
        form.submit();
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Someone just requested that URL via the browser, is my best guess

Comment: I would say this is most probably some kind of bot or so crawling and trying to access any URL found in source code... there is no way this piece of HTML (without an underlying javascript) would issue a `GET` request

Comment: @JimmyKnoot  That's also the only guess I'm making. But then they must know the URL (no link to it) and the time they are on the page is to short to do a inspect element and filter the URL from it. Besides that, the order crashes but the user takes the effort to reorder it again. And the second time the form is posted to the server.

Comment: @Bartdude, no, they are real people, that's for sure (the order crashes and they do it a second time). However, there is a Javascript validation (jquery validation). I will update my question.